# How to I combine terraform maps?

Tags: terraform

I have the following data in terraform:

```json
locals {
  items = { 
    foo = {
      config = {
        prefix = "foo-prefix:"
        values = {
          "key1" : "value1",
          "key2" : "value2"
        }
      }
    },
    bar = {
      config = {
        prefix = "bar-prefix:"
        values = {
          "key3" : "value3",
          "key4" : "value4"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  result = { for k, v in local.items: k =>  {
     for a, b in v.config.values :
        "${v.config.prefix}${a}" => b 
  }
}


output "result" {
  value = local.result
}
```

Which yields:

```json
result = {
  "bar" = {
    "bar-prefix:key3" = "value3"
    "bar-prefix:key4" = "value4"
  }
  "foo" = {
    "foo-prefix:key1" = "value1"
    "foo-prefix:key2" = "value2"
  }
}
```

But I'm trying to get:

```json
result = {
  "bar-prefix:key3" = "value3"
  "bar-prefix:key4" = "value4"
  "foo-prefix:key1" = "value1"
  "foo-prefix:key2" = "value2"
}
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out terraform has a nifty ellipses operator (`...`) that expands lists into argument parameters:

```json
output "result" {
  value = merge([
    for k, v in local.items :{
      for a, b in v.config.values : "${v.config.prefix}${a}" =>  b 
    }
  ]...)
}
```